# Simple Singleton EJB Example

Tags: java, ejb

I'm learning EJB's and have written an example program using GlassFish 4 but for some reason it's not working.

**index.jsp**:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="javax.ejb.EJB" %>
<%@ page import="ejbtest.utility.Utility" %>
<%@ page import="ejbtest.action.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>EJB Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            try {
                Utility utility = new Utility();
                out.println("count: " + utility.getCount() + "<br/><br/>");
                Trigger1 trigger1 = new Trigger1();
                out.println("trigger1 count: " + trigger1.getTriggerCount());
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                out.println("Nullpointer caught");
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Utility.java**:

```
package ejbtest.utility;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class Utility {

    int count;

    public Utility() throws NullPointerException {
        count = 0;
        count++;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

**Trigger1.java**:

```
package ejbtest.action;

import ejbtest.utility.Utility;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class Trigger1 {

    @Inject
    Utility utility;

    public Integer getTriggerCount() {
        return utility.getCount();
    }

}
```

**Undesired Output**:

> count: 1
>
> Nullpointer caught

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you start yours EJB in standart JVM. But EJB can live only inside EJB Container. When you start your application just using main method all EJB annotations ignored. You need application server like glassfish or JBoss to test your application.
 Here your improved example: 
  **Trigger1.java**

```
package ejbtest.action;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import ejbtest.utility.Utility;

@Stateless
public class Trigger1 {

    @EJB
    private Utility utility;

    public Integer getTriggerCount() {
        return utility.getCount();
    }
}
```

**Utility.java**

```
package ejbtest.utility;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class Utility {
    int count = 0;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        count++;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page import="ejbtest.action.Trigger1"%>
<%@page import="ejbtest.utility.Utility"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>EJB Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        Utility utility = (Utility) ic.lookup("java:module/Utility");
        out.println("count: " + utility.getCount() + "<br/><br/>");
        Trigger1 trigger1 = (Trigger1) ic.lookup("java:module/Trigger1");
        out.println("trigger1 count: " + trigger1.getTriggerCount());
    %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it inside Tomcat 7 and GlassFish 4 as a JSP scriptlet instead of a main class but I got the same thing...

Comment: Show scriplet code. If you did it the same as here new Trigger1(), so it is wrong. Object created by your self creates outside EJB container and EJB annotations ignored. Your Trigger1 object must be created by EJB container.

Comment: As I said you use new operator to get your EJB. It is wrong, you should use initial context go get link for you EJB. Some thing like: InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(); Utility utility = (Utility)ic.lookup("Utility");

Comment: Can't I just use an annotation to do the `lookup` if I'm using EJB 3.2? I thought that's what `@Local`, `@EJB` and `@Remote` etc were for?

Comment: Look my edits. You can use annotation during injection one EJB inside others. But if you use EJB inside jsp pages you have to use InitialContext

Answer (score 1):

I think you can inject `EJB` only in other `Session Beans` or `Message-Driven Beans`. In your Code you try to inject them into simple java classes. You can reference them in java classes with `JNDI lookup`.

If your classes `Trigger1` and `Trigger2` are not in the same (`Java EE`) application as your `Utility` Bean , then you need `Remote` access and therefore an interface view. You can then access the `Singleton` Bean as follows: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project.

If your `Trigger1` and `Trigger2` classes are in the same apllication as your `Utility` Bean, then the Local no interface view which you already provide is sufficient. You can access the `Singleton` Bean through `Injection` as you do, but you have to make your classes `Session` Beans (preferably Stateless). Then you should again through `JNDI lookup` to access them from your main method.

Comment: Could you possibly show me what code to change by any chance as I'm still fairly new to all of this terminology when it comes to putting it into practice